# Github & Heroku Webhooks : Add label when pushed to origin, close when pushed to prod

Tags: git, heroku, github

I love webhooks. Github has them, heroku also. We extensively use the commit messages `Fixes #345 git commit message that will close issue 345 when pushed to origin`

What I'd like to achieve is:

- When I push to `origin`, a label is added to the issue, something like `Fixed`
- When I push to my heroku `dev` app, a label is added to the issue, something like `In Dev`
- When I push to my heroku `prod` app, the issue is actually closed.

Is there a way I can achieve this?

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, this can't be done by pluging heroku straight to github, as some little data processing is necessary.

I also checked on [If this then that](https://ifttt.com) if it could be possible, but unfortunately, there is no room for running a little script there, as far as I checked...

I ended up writing my own heroku app that does the job.

https://github.com/copass/copass-hook

1. When pushed to github, it is actually closed (normal behaviour).
2. When pushed to dev, a milestone is applied 'In Dev'
3. When pushed to prod, a milestone is applied 'In Prod'

I considered it more interesting to use milestones as we don't currently use them. But it would be the same logic.

Don't hesitate to fork the app if you like it!

Answer (score 1):

You can add your own Web Hooks to GitHub using their [Web Hooks API](http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/hooks/).

That should take care of *when* to run a web hook, but you will need to write you own code for  adding labels to your issues which you be achievable using [their Issues API](http://developer.github.com/v3/issues/labels/).

For Heroku, you'll have to setup a [HTTP POST Hook](https://addons.heroku.com/deployhooks#http) using their Deploy Hooks addon.